# Display searched text with line numbers in a text file

Tags: java

So I've been working on a program that will display the line number and the line itself of the searched text string. If I search dog, and I have lines in my text file that contain the word dog, those lines and line numbers should be shown. I also have created a method that counts the characters, words, and lines of a text file. However, the problem I am having is that whenever I run my program I don't get the line numbers with the lines of the searched text. I successfully get the text from the text file in the console and I successfully get the number of lines, words, etc.

Here's my written code, I am guessing it has to do something with the fact that I don't have a "return results;" statement, but I am not sure where to put it, and if I add it to the end of "+ characters + " characters. "" line by doing "+ results", it just gives me empty brackets.

Maybe I am doing something wrong? Perhaps something to do with closing the file and stream, not sure. Please help, I've tried moving stuff around but no luck.

```
public String words() {
    try {
        int words = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        int lines = 1;
        int characters = 0;
        int total = 0;

        String c = " ";

        FileReader r = new FileReader(file1);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(r);
        StreamTokenizer t = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        t.resetSyntax();
        t.wordChars('0', '9');
        t.wordChars('A', 'Z');
        t.wordChars('a', 'z');
        t.whitespaceChars(0, ' ');

        t.eolIsSignificant(true);

        while (t.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            switch (t.ttype) {
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                    numbers++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                    characters += t.sval.length();
                    words++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
                    lines++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                    break;
                default:

            }
        }

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }

        br.close();

        String ask = "Enter Word";

        String find = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ask);
        String word = find;

        String line = null;
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                results.add(lnr.getLineNumber() + line);
            }
        }

        r.close();

        total = numbers + words;

        lnr.close();

        return file1.getName() + " has " + lines + " lines, "
                + total + " words, "
                + characters + " characters. ";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        display(e.toString(), "Error");
    }

    return " ";

}
```

Here's the main class if needed:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicFile {

File file1;
JFileChooser selection;
File file2 = new File(".", "Backup File");

public BasicFile() {
    selection = new JFileChooser(".");
}

public void selectFile() {
    int status = selection.showOpenDialog(null);

    try {
        if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        file1 = selection.getSelectedFile();

        if (!file1.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found ", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void backupFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1));
        out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file2));

        try {
            while (true) {
                byte data = in.readByte();
                out.writeByte(data);
            }
        } catch (EOFException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File has been backed up!",
                    "Backup Complete!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Not Found ",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            display(e.toString(), "Error");
        }
    }

}

boolean exists() {
    return file1.exists();
}

public String toString() {
    return file1.getName() + "\n" + file1.getAbsolutePath() + "\n" + file1.length() + " bytes";
}

public String words() {
    try {
        int words = 0;
        int numbers = 0;
        int lines = 1;
        int characters = 0;
        int total = 0;

        String c = " ";

        FileReader r = new FileReader(file1);
        LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(r);
        StreamTokenizer t = new StreamTokenizer(r);
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        t.resetSyntax();
        t.wordChars('0', '9');
        t.wordChars('A', 'Z');
        t.wordChars('a', 'z');
        t.whitespaceChars(0, ' ');

        t.eolIsSignificant(true);

        while (t.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            switch (t.ttype) {
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                    numbers++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                    characters += t.sval.length();
                    words++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL:
                    lines++;
                    break;
                case StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF:
                    break;
                default:

            }
        }

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(strLine);
        }

        br.close();

        String ask = "Enter Word";

        String find = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ask);
        String word = find;

        String line = null;
        while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                results.add(lnr.getLineNumber() + line);
            }
        }

        r.close();

        total = numbers + words;

        lnr.close();

        return file1.getName() + " has " + lines + " lines, "
                + total + " words, "
                + characters + " characters. ";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        display(e.toString(), "Error");
    }

    return " ";

}

void display(String msg, String s) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, s, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there.

reinitialize your FileReader and LineNumberReader before your `while ((line = lnr.readLine()) != null)` loop.

Then your ArrayList will be full of the #String that I think you desire.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is *start counting the lines in the file* (`starting by 0`), then `increase by 1` *every time a new line is found*.. then *check if the string you want to find is contained in the line*, then `print the number of the line where the keyword is found` (using the `contains()` function in Java). I assumed you want to check for both upper and lower case, if you don't want that then simply remove the `toLowerCase()` ! So, read the file properly in Java:

```
        long lineNumber = 0;
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")); 
        String line = myReader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                lineNumber++;
                System.out.println("The line I am now examining is : " + line + " and the line number is : " + lineNumber);
                if line.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase()) {
                System.out.println("Line number: " + lineNumber + " contains keyword : " + word);
                line = myReader.readLine();
            }
```